# Find the latest created JSON using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Lets say i have a folder which contains of several different file types. One among them are JSON files. It is not always so that the latest created file in the folder is a JSON file.

My problem is that i need to find the latest  **JSON** file, not the latest file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code so far. Do the JSON files have a *.json extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Get-ChildItem (gci) and filter on *.json

You can then sort by LastWriteTime in descending order and retrieve the first item in the array of files.

```
$jsonFiles = gci c:\jsonFiles -Filter *.json

($jsonFiles | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending)[0]
```